# JQuery Add Row after Add Table

Tags: jquery

Adding a new table function works and adding a row function works on tables that were already created on the page. However, when I try adding a row to a table that I added dynamically it does not work.

The alert for testing when I click add row does not do anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".addtable").on("click", function () {

            $(".order-list:last").each(function() {
                closesttable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
                tableid = closesttable.replace(/^.+-/,'');
            });
            tableid=parseInt(tableid)+1;

            var newTable = $("<div class='tableDemo'>");
            var cols = "<table id='table-"+tableid+"' class='order-list'>";

            cols += '<tbody><tr id="1"><td>'+tableid+'</td>';
            cols += '<td>1</td>';
            cols += '<td>1</td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" name="Quantity['+tableid+'][1]" value=""/></td>';
            cols += '<td><select name="Meal['+tableid+'][1]"><option></option><option>Chicken</option><option>Fish</option><option>Bison</option></select></td>';

            cols += "<td><input type='submit' name='Delete["+tableid+"][1]' value='Delete' id='ibtnDel' style='height: 20px;'><a class='deleteRow'></a></td></tr>";
            cols += "</tbody><tfoot><tr id='addrow1'><td colspan=5><input type='button' class='addrow' value='Add Row' style='height: 20px;'></td></tr></tfoot></table></div>";

            newTable.append(cols);

            $("#here_table").append(newTable);

            $(".addrow").on("click", function () {
                alert("new addrow clicked");
            });

        });

    });
```

```
<div id="here_table"></div>
<BR><BR>
<input type='button' class='addtable' value='Add Table'>
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: tableid is not defined`

Comment: Also, to make dynamic, change `$(".addtable").on("click", function () {` to the dynamic use of `on` or `.delegate`, like: `$(document).on('click', '.addtable', function(e) {` OR `$(document).delegate('.addtable', 'click', function(e) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$(".addrow").on("click", function () {
    alert("new addrow clicked");
});
```

to

```
$(document).on("click",".addrow", function () {
    alert("new addrow clicked");
});
```

See jQuery's docs on [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more info on event delegation.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Comment: So weird. I am starting to think that in order to downvote you should be required to leave a comment.